# How to use e.findAt for similar geometrical models?

Tags: scripting, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I used Abaqus macro recording when defining a set: by edge (20 deg). My end goal is to run the script for different `.STEP` models/geometries which are identical in every aspect except for a few parametric values. For each model I am using the same procedure for selecting the highlighted edges: create a set from edge-by-angle-20.
However, when I run it for other geometric models, it selects an entirely different `e.getSequenceFromMask` or as I should say entirely different sets for `e.findAt` after running the commands for the similar edge.

```py
session.journalOptions.replayGeometry
session.journalOptions.setValues(replayGeometry=INDEX)
```

I am aware that the program has restrictions over findAt :

**findAt initially uses the ACIS tolerance of 1E-6. As a result, findAt returns any edge that is at the arbitrary point specified or at a distance of less than 1E-6 from the arbitrary point.**

[Edge to be selected in all models which are similar with a few variations in dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZMZl.png)

I would appreciate it if anyone can suggest how to ensure the same edges are selected for different geometries when using the `e.findAt` command.

My code:

```py
#Sample for the same edges selected from different dimensioned CAD models
#CAD Model_1
edges = e.getSequenceFromMask(mask=(
    '[#63002104 #88110 #10000480 #20402 #480c802 #10420070 #c4411',
    ' #70104842 #10022000 #1e2002 #30 #80820010 #20003 #18144186',
    ' #b000 ]',), )
p.Set(edges=edges, name='Set-2')

#Set 2:
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 10'].edges.findAt(((2.808153, 3.86272, -0.231317),),((3.959929, 2.669325, -0.231317),),((3.581888, 1.932068, -0.134932),),((1.501975, 3.782442, -0.134931),),((2.094736, 4.291667, -0.231317),),((2.135971, 3.464163, -0.134931),),((2.705066, 3.040627, -0.134931),),((3.436245, 3.316406, -0.231317),),((3.19197, 2.524704, -0.134932),),((4.363292, 1.941137, -0.231317),),((3.862971, 1.280728, -0.134932),),((-0.318814, 3.68708, 0.0),),((1.317672, 4.590214, -0.231317),),((4.764061, 0.331739, -0.231318),),((4.74929, -0.500571, -0.231318),),((4.590214, -1.317672, -0.231317),),((4.634078, 1.15397, -0.231318),),((-0.590217, 4.023581, -0.132766),),((-0.331245, 4.765369, -0.229231),),((0.822343, 3.985795, -0.134932),),((0.500571, 4.74929, -0.231318),),((4.02668, 0.590473, -0.134933),),((4.068041, -0.117724, -0.134933),),((4.291667, -2.094736, -0.231317),),((3.464163, -2.135971, -0.134931),),((3.86272, -2.808153, -0.231317),),((1.932068, -3.581888, -0.134932),),((1.280728, -3.862971, -0.134932),),((1.15397, -4.634078, -0.231318),),((0.590473, -4.02668, -0.134933),),((-0.117724, -4.068041, -0.134933),),((3.985795, -0.822343, -0.134932),),((0.117724, 4.068041, -0.134933),),((-1.15397, 4.634078, -0.231318),),((-1.280728, 3.862971, -0.134932),),((-2.524704, 3.19197, -0.134932),),((-2.669325, 3.959929, -0.231317),),((-1.941137, 4.363292, -0.231317),),((-1.932068, 3.581888, -0.134932),),((3.782442, -1.501975, -0.134931),),((3.040627, -2.705066, -0.134931),),((3.316406, -3.436245, -0.231317),),((2.524704, -3.19197, -0.134932),),((2.669325, -3.959929, -0.231317),),((1.941137, -4.363292, -0.231317),),((0.331739, -4.764061, -0.231318),),((-0.500571, -4.74929, -0.231318),),((-3.464163, 2.135971, -0.134931),),((-4.291667, 2.094736, -0.231317),),((-3.316406, 3.436245, -0.231317),),((-3.040627, 2.705066, -0.134931),),((-3.86272, 2.808153, -0.231317),),((-1.317672, -4.590214, -0.231317),),((-0.822343, -3.985795, -0.134932),),((-4.764061, -0.331739, -0.231318),),((-3.959929, -2.669325, -0.231317),),((-3.862971, -1.280728, -0.134932),),((-3.782442, 1.501975, -0.134931),),((-4.590214, 1.317672, -0.231317),),((-3.985795, 0.822343, -0.134932),),((-2.135971, -3.464163, -0.134931),),((-4.74929, 0.500571, -0.231318),),((-4.068041, 0.117724, -0.134933),),((-4.02668, -0.590473, -0.134933),),((-4.634078, -1.15397, -0.231318),),((-4.363292, -1.941137, -0.231317),),((-3.581888, -1.932068, -0.134932),),((-3.19197, -2.524704, -0.134932),),((-3.436245, -3.316406, -0.231317),),((-2.705066, -3.040627, -0.134931),),((-2.094736, -4.291667, -0.231317),),((-1.501975, -3.782442, -0.134931),),((-2.808153, -3.86272, -0.231317),),)


#CAD Model_2
edges = e.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#ffffffff:12 #3fffff ]', ), )
p.Set(edges=edges, name='Set-2')

#Set_2:
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 9'].edges.findAt(((3.609683, 0.972388, 1e-06),),((3.573439, 0.962676, 0.012491),),((3.76173, 1.266747, -0.034239),),((4.345677, 1.895909, -0.106922),),((3.369331, 1.576662, 0.046191),),((3.59632, 1.879201, -0.101049),),((4.017677, 2.705061, -0.092682),),((3.044359, 2.137787, 0.046191),),((3.950435, 2.621725, -0.106922),),((4.319341, 2.493773, 0.001066),),((3.51041, 1.897727, -0.09198),),((4.38626, 1.924207, -0.137251),),((3.786618, 1.25932, -0.091981),),((4.653757, 1.133308, -0.137251),),((3.94777, 0.582649, -0.091981),),((4.779853, 0.307975, -0.137252),),((4.987546, 0.0, 0.001066),),((3.968123, -0.096234, -0.034239),),((3.706257, -0.319236, 0.046191),),((4.054105, -0.170725, -0.101049),),((4.831941, 0.333813, -0.092682),),((3.705386, 0.329198, 0.046191),),((3.686317, 0.32753, 0.012491),),((3.591928, 0.967631, 0.046191),),((4.608877, 1.112487, -0.106922),),((3.924549, 0.594285, -0.034239),),((4.732039, 0.295263, -0.106922),),((4.68676, 1.705841, 0.001066),),((3.351983, 1.568572, 0.012491),),((3.38599, 1.58443, 1e-06),),((4.426368, 1.966302, -0.092682),),((3.868004, 1.226157, -0.101049),),((4.700566, 1.167799, -0.092682),),((4.02216, 0.535857, -0.101049),),((3.723697, 0.3308, 1e-06),),((4.332897, 2.501599, 0.037363),),((3.215364, 2.475146, -0.101049),),((3.059416, 2.14833, 1e-06),),((3.028679, 2.126808, 0.012491),),((3.101617, 2.476941, -0.034239),),((3.435161, 3.267881, -0.106922),),((2.613351, 2.620422, 0.012491),),((2.649644, 2.983909, -0.091979),),((2.83651, 3.859543, -0.137251),),((2.134748, 3.057453, 1e-06),),((2.14551, 3.072822, 2e-06),),((2.850196, 3.916052, -0.092682),),((3.215994, 3.832672, 0.037363),),((3.205932, 3.820682, 0.001066),),((2.815512, 3.814744, -0.106922),),((2.129595, 3.050095, 0.046191),),((2.174904, 3.425595, -0.101049),),((2.501599, 4.332897, 0.037363),),((2.493773, 4.319341, 0.001066),),((2.067403, 3.388378, -0.034239),),((3.484612, 1.90072, -0.034239),),((3.985488, 2.656641, -0.137251),),((4.701469, 1.711195, 0.037363),),((4.927189, 0.868796, 0.037363),),((5.003198, 0.0, 0.037363),),((4.711421, -0.530933, -0.106922),),((3.891127, -0.78383, -0.034239),),((4.547648, -1.340996, -0.106922),),((3.695902, -1.447609, -0.034239),),((3.356209, -1.559509, 0.012491),),((3.710189, -1.469294, -0.091979),),((4.68676, -1.705841, 0.001066),),((4.816498, -0.510316, -0.092682),),((3.724569, -0.320838, 1e-06),),((3.687189, -0.317568, 0.012491),),((4.911774, 0.866078, 0.001066),),((3.48691, 3.361627, -0.092682),),((2.626886, 2.633957, 0.046191),),((3.127541, 2.478471, -0.091979),),((3.463619, 3.308353, -0.137251),),((2.639883, 2.646954, 1e-06),),((3.820682, 3.205932, 0.001066),),((3.832672, 3.215994, 0.037363),),((2.62438, 2.9779, -0.034239),),((2.118616, 3.034415, 0.012491),),((2.091239, 3.398682, -0.091979),),((2.736711, 2.995885, -0.101049),),((2.12688, 4.35149, -0.092682),),((1.547014, 3.751221, -0.101049),),((1.711195, 4.701469, 0.037363),),((1.469294, 3.710189, -0.091979),),((2.123214, 4.293462, -0.137251),),((2.110314, 4.245698, -0.106922),),((3.988971, -0.111726, -0.091981),),((4.911774, -0.866078, 0.001066),),((4.760715, -0.526717, -0.137252),),((3.594516, -0.957971, 0.046191),),((3.576027, -0.953017, 0.012491),),((3.908966, -0.802706, -0.09198),),((4.927189, -0.868796, 0.037363),),((3.373557, -1.567599, 0.046191),),((4.245698, -2.110314, -0.106922),),((4.319341, -2.493773, 0.001066),),((4.332897, -2.501599, 0.037363),),((4.35149, -2.12688, -0.092682),),((4.293462, -2.123214, -0.137251),),((3.390216, -1.575367, 1e-06),),((4.596926, -1.345405, -0.137251),),((3.612271, -0.962729, 1e-06),),((4.65471, -1.338939, -0.092682),),((3.751221, -1.547014, -0.101049),),((3.962868, -0.872119, -0.101049),),((1.567599, 3.373557, 0.046191),),((1.338939, 4.65471, -0.092682),),((0.872119, 3.962868, -0.101049),),((0.510316, 4.816498, -0.092682),),((0.321655, 3.733897, 2e-06),),((0.320019, 3.715207, 1e-06),),((0.111726, 3.988971, -0.091981),),((0.0, 4.987546, 0.001066),),((0.096234, 3.968123, -0.034239),),((0.530933, 4.711421, -0.106922),),((0.866078, 4.911774, 0.001066),),((0.526717, 4.760715, -0.137252),),((1.705841, 4.68676, 0.001066),),((1.345405, 4.596926, -0.137251),),((0.802706, 3.908966, -0.09198),),((1.571395, 3.381699, 1e-06),),((1.579324, 3.398703, 2e-06),),((1.447609, 3.695902, -0.034239),),((1.559509, 3.356209, 0.012491),),((3.388378, -2.067403, -0.034239),),((3.050095, -2.129595, 0.046191),),((3.065152, -2.140139, 1e-06),),((3.034415, -2.118616, 0.012491),),((3.398682, -2.091239, -0.091979),),((3.425595, -2.174904, -0.101049),),((4.701469, -1.711195, 0.037363),),((0.965152, 3.621316, 2e-06),),((0.957971, 3.594516, 0.046191),),((0.953017, 3.576027, 0.012491),),((0.868796, 4.927189, 0.037363),),((0.319236, 3.706257, 0.046191),),((0.170725, 4.054105, -0.101049),),((0.0, 5.003198, 0.037363),),((-0.3073, 4.782091, -0.136321),),((-0.320838, 3.724565, 1e-05),),((-0.323171, 3.73689, 1.3e-05),),((-0.324216, 3.705803, 0.046199),),((-0.593805, 3.921017, -0.033079),),((-0.866078, 4.911774, 0.001066),),((-1.133308, 4.653757, -0.137251),),((-0.972388, 3.609683, 1e-06),),((-0.967631, 3.591928, 0.046191),),((-1.112487, 4.608877, -0.106922),),((0.317568, 3.687189, 0.012491),),((-0.294772, 4.734331, -0.106051),),((0.78383, 3.891127, -0.034239),),((1.340996, 4.547648, -0.106922),),((0.960296, 3.603193, 1e-06),),((3.814744, -2.815512, -0.106922),),((3.820682, -3.205932, 0.001066),),((3.832672, -3.215994, 0.037363),),((3.916052, -2.850196, -0.092682),),((3.859543, -2.83651, -0.137251),),((-0.332828, 4.834011, -0.091687),),((-0.318814, 3.68708, 0.0),),((-0.325817, 3.724111, 1e-05),),((-0.536001, 4.018603, -0.099875),),((-0.868796, 4.927189, 0.037363),),((-0.319237, 3.706259, 0.046191),),((-0.322549, 3.68675, 0.0125),),((-0.31881, 3.687067, 0.05),),((-0.317568, 3.687186, 0.012495),),((-0.582378, 3.944173, -0.090789),),((-0.962676, 3.573439, 0.012491),),((-1.25932, 3.786618, -0.091981),),((-1.711195, 4.701469, 0.037363),),((-1.226157, 3.868004, -0.101049),),((-1.167799, 4.700566, -0.092682),),((2.9779, -2.62438, -0.034239),),((3.267881, -3.435161, -0.106922),),((2.476941, -3.101617, -0.034239),),((2.137787, -3.044359, 0.046191),),((2.475146, -3.215364, -0.101049),),((3.361627, -3.48691, -0.092682),),((2.633957, -2.626886, 0.046191),),((2.620422, -2.613351, 0.012491),),((2.983909, -2.649644, -0.091979),),((2.995885, -2.736711, -0.101049),),((2.646954, -2.639883, 1e-06),),((-1.266747, 3.76173, -0.034239),),((-1.705841, 4.68676, 0.001066),),((-1.924207, 4.38626, -0.137251),),((-1.58443, 3.38599, 1e-06),),((-1.966302, 4.426368, -0.092682),),((3.205932, -3.820682, 0.001066),),((2.478471, -3.127541, -0.091979),),((2.656641, -3.985488, -0.137251),),((2.493773, -4.319341, 0.001066),),((1.90072, -3.484612, -0.034239),),((1.576662, -3.369331, 0.046191),),((1.879201, -3.59632, -0.101049),),((2.705061, -4.017677, -0.092682),),((2.126808, -3.028679, 0.012491),),((2.14833, -3.059416, 1e-06),),((3.215994, -3.832672, 0.037363),),((3.308353, -3.463619, -0.137251),),((-1.895909, 4.345677, -0.106922),),((-1.568572, 3.351983, 0.012491),),((-1.897727, 3.51041, -0.09198),),((-2.501599, 4.332897, 0.037363),),((-2.705061, 4.017677, -0.092682),),((-2.137787, 3.044359, 0.046191),),((-2.621725, 3.950435, -0.106922),),((-2.493773, 4.319341, 0.001066),),((-2.656641, 3.985488, -0.137251),),((-2.14833, 3.059416, 1e-06),),((-1.576662, 3.369331, 0.046191),),((2.501599, -4.332897, 0.037363),),((2.621725, -3.950435, -0.106922),),((1.895909, -4.345677, -0.106922),),((1.705841, -4.68676, 0.001066),),((1.924207, -4.38626, -0.137251),),((1.58443, -3.38599, 1e-06),),((1.966302, -4.426368, -0.092682),),((-1.90072, 3.484612, -0.034239),),((-1.879201, 3.59632, -0.101049),),((-2.475146, 3.215364, -0.101049),),((-2.476941, 3.101617, -0.034239),),((-2.126808, 3.028679, 0.012491),),((-2.478471, 3.127541, -0.091979),),((-3.308353, 3.463619, -0.137251),),((-2.646954, 2.639883, 1e-06),),((-3.361627, 3.48691, -0.092682),),((-3.215994, 3.832672, 0.037363),),((1.897727, -3.51041, -0.09198),),((1.568572, -3.351983, 0.012491),),((1.266747, -3.76173, -0.034239),),((0.967631, -3.591928, 0.046191),),((0.972388, -3.609683, 1e-06),),((0.962676, -3.573439, 0.012491),),((1.112487, -4.608877, -0.106922),),((0.594285, -3.924549, -0.034239),),((0.329198, -3.705386, 0.046191),),((0.535857, -4.02216, -0.101049),),((1.167799, -4.700566, -0.092682),),((1.226157, -3.868004, -0.101049),),((1.711195, -4.701469, 0.037363),),((1.25932, -3.786618, -0.091981),),((-3.267881, 3.435161, -0.106922),),((-3.205932, 3.820682, 0.001066),),((-2.620422, 2.613351, 0.012491),),((-2.983909, 2.649644, -0.091979),),((-3.859543, 2.83651, -0.137251),),((-3.065152, 2.140139, 1e-06),),((-3.050095, 2.129595, 0.046191),),((-3.034415, 2.118616, 0.012491),),((-3.398682, 2.091239, -0.091979),),)+mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 9'].edges.findAt(((-4.319341, 2.493773, 0.001066),),((-4.245698, 2.110314, -0.106922),),((-3.695902, 1.447609, -0.034239),),((-4.547648, 1.340996, -0.106922),),((-3.576027, 0.953017, 0.012491),),((-3.908966, 0.802706, -0.09198),),((-4.760715, 0.526717, -0.137252),),((-3.724569, 0.320838, 1e-06),),((-4.816498, 0.510316, -0.092682),),((-3.962868, 0.872119, -0.101049),),((-3.612271, 0.962729, 1e-06),),((-2.633957, 2.626886, 0.046191),),((0.866078, -4.911774, 0.001066),),((1.133308, -4.653757, -0.137251),),((0.295263, -4.732039, -0.106922),),((-0.096234, -3.968123, -0.034239),),((-0.530933, -4.711421, -0.106922),),((-0.78383, -3.891127, -0.034239),),((-0.957971, -3.594516, 0.046191),),((-0.872119, -3.962868, -0.101049),),((-0.868796, -4.927189, 0.037363),),((-0.802706, -3.908966, -0.09198),),((-1.345405, -4.596926, -0.137251),),((-1.711195, -4.701469, 0.037363),),((-1.338939, -4.65471, -0.092682),),((0.3308, -3.723697, 1e-06),),((0.333813, -4.831941, -0.092682),),((0.0, -5.003198, 0.037363),),((0.0, -4.987546, 0.001066),),((0.868796, -4.927189, 0.037363),),((-2.9779, 2.62438, -0.034239),),((-3.820682, 3.205932, 0.001066),),((-3.832672, 3.215994, 0.037363),),((-3.916052, 2.850196, -0.092682),),((-3.425595, 2.174904, -0.101049),),((-3.388378, 2.067403, -0.034239),),((-3.814744, 2.815512, -0.106922),),((-4.293462, 2.123214, -0.137251),),((-3.390216, 1.575367, 1e-06),),((-4.35149, 2.12688, -0.092682),),((-4.332897, 2.501599, 0.037363),),((-3.373557, 1.567599, 0.046191),),((-3.356209, 1.559509, 0.012491),),((-3.710189, 1.469294, -0.091979),),((-4.701469, 1.711195, 0.037363),),((-4.65471, 1.338939, -0.092682),),((-3.594516, 0.957971, 0.046191),),((-4.68676, 1.705841, 0.001066),),((-4.596926, 1.345405, -0.137251),),((-3.891127, 0.78383, -0.034239),),((-4.927189, 0.868796, 0.037363),),((-3.687189, 0.317568, 0.012491),),((-3.988971, 0.111726, -0.091981),),((-4.779853, -0.307975, -0.137252),),((-3.723697, -0.3308, 1e-06),),((-4.831941, -0.333813, -0.092682),),((-4.054105, 0.170725, -0.101049),),((-3.706257, 0.319236, 0.046191),),((-4.711421, 0.530933, -0.106922),),((-4.911774, 0.866078, 0.001066),),((-2.995885, 2.736711, -0.101049),),((0.32753, -3.686317, 0.012491),),((0.582649, -3.94777, -0.091981),),((-0.319236, -3.706257, 0.046191),),((-0.317568, -3.687189, 0.012491),),((-0.111726, -3.988971, -0.091981),),((0.307975, -4.779853, -0.137252),),((-0.866078, -4.911774, 0.001066),),((-0.526717, -4.760715, -0.137252),),((-0.320838, -3.724569, 1e-06),),((-0.510316, -4.816498, -0.092682),),((-0.953017, -3.576027, 0.012491),),((-0.962729, -3.612271, 1e-06),),((-1.705841, -4.68676, 0.001066),),((-1.469294, -3.710189, -0.091979),),((-2.123214, -4.293462, -0.137251),),((-2.091239, -3.398682, -0.091979),),((-2.83651, -3.859543, -0.137251),),((-2.649644, -2.983909, -0.091979),),((-3.463619, -3.308353, -0.137251),),((-3.820682, -3.205932, 0.001066),),((-3.101617, -2.476941, -0.034239),),((-3.044359, -2.137787, 0.046191),),((-3.215364, -2.475146, -0.101049),),((-3.832672, -3.215994, 0.037363),),((-3.127541, -2.478471, -0.091979),),((-3.985488, -2.656641, -0.137251),),((-4.332897, -2.501599, 0.037363),),((-3.59632, -1.879201, -0.101049),),((-3.38599, -1.58443, 1e-06),),((-3.351983, -1.568572, 0.012491),),((-3.484612, -1.90072, -0.034239),),((-4.319341, -2.493773, 0.001066),),((-1.547014, -3.751221, -0.101049),),((-1.575367, -3.390216, 1e-06),),((-1.559509, -3.356209, 0.012491),),((-1.567599, -3.373557, 0.046191),),((-0.170725, -4.054105, -0.101049),),((-3.751221, 1.547014, -0.101049),),((-3.968123, 0.096234, -0.034239),),((-5.003198, 0.0, 0.037363),),((-3.686317, -0.32753, 0.012491),),((-3.94777, -0.582649, -0.091981),),((-4.653757, -1.133308, -0.137251),),((-3.609683, -0.972388, 1e-06),),((-3.591928, -0.967631, 0.046191),),((-4.608877, -1.112487, -0.106922),),((-4.911774, -0.866078, 0.001066),),((-3.705386, -0.329198, 0.046191),),((-4.732039, -0.295263, -0.106922),),((-1.340996, -4.547648, -0.106922),),((-1.447609, -3.695902, -0.034239),),((-2.501599, -4.332897, 0.037363),),((-2.174904, -3.425595, -0.101049),),((-2.850196, -3.916052, -0.092682),),((-2.736711, -2.995885, -0.101049),),((-2.639883, -2.646954, 1e-06),),((-2.613351, -2.620422, 0.012491),),((-3.435161, -3.267881, -0.106922),),((-2.140139, -3.065152, 1e-06),),((-2.129595, -3.050095, 0.046191),),((-2.815512, -3.814744, -0.106922),),((-3.205932, -3.820682, 0.001066),),((-3.215994, -3.832672, 0.037363),),((-3.950435, -2.621725, -0.106922),),((-3.059416, -2.14833, 1e-06),),((-4.017677, -2.705061, -0.092682),),((-3.48691, -3.361627, -0.092682),),((-2.626886, -2.633957, 0.046191),),((-3.51041, -1.897727, -0.09198),),((-4.426368, -1.966302, -0.092682),),((-3.369331, -1.576662, 0.046191),),((-4.345677, -1.895909, -0.106922),),((-4.68676, -1.705841, 0.001066),),((-3.786618, -1.25932, -0.091981),),((-2.12688, -4.35149, -0.092682),),((-2.110314, -4.245698, -0.106922),),((-2.493773, -4.319341, 0.001066),),((-4.987546, 0.0, 0.001066),),((-4.927189, -0.868796, 0.037363),),((-4.700566, -1.167799, -0.092682),),((-3.573439, -0.962676, 0.012491),),((-3.868004, -1.226157, -0.101049),),((-3.76173, -1.266747, -0.034239),),((-3.924549, -0.594285, -0.034239),),((-4.02216, -0.535857, -0.101049),),((-2.62438, -2.9779, -0.034239),),((-2.118616, -3.034415, 0.012491),),((-2.067403, -3.388378, -0.034239),),((-3.028679, -2.126808, 0.012491),),((-4.38626, -1.924207, -0.137251),),((-4.701469, -1.711195, 0.037363),),)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Do not use `getSequenceFromMask`

This method seems very appealing, however, Abaqus documentation does not cover how masks are formed, so it is not possible to artificially generate a mask for a set of objects.

#### Use coordinates (`findAt()`) or indeces instead

Most of the time if your geometry is complex and is generated without control over vertices/edges/etc numbering then the `findAt()` method is your only option (along with methods `getByBoundingBox(...)`, `getByBoundingCylinder(...)` and `getByBoundingSphere(...)`).

If searching edge-by-edge is not very efficient and `getByBounding...` methods do not allow you to select the right array of edges then you can try: 1) to find the first edge of your sequence; 2) then use (as you already tried) the `getEdgesByEdgeAngle(...)` method to find all adjacent edges.

If you know for sure the numbering of your geometrical entities (vertices/edges/etc.) then you can access them by their index. So, using notations from your example, if edges of interest of your geometry have indexes from `n` to `m` then:

```py
part = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Circular_knit - 2, 3, 10']

set2 = part.Set(name='Set-2', edges=part.edges[n:m+1])
```